# Use OCMock to verify if a method is invoked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ocmock, sentestingkit

Im a beginner to OCMock and I need to verify if a method is invoked from another class. The following is my code.

```
 //Creating the OCMockObject
id mockProductRequest = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[ProductRequest class]];
[[mockProductRequest expect] testProductRequest];

//Creating the object where the mock object will be invoked
ProductService *actualService = [[ProductService alloc] init];
[actualService testProductService];

[mockProductRequest verify];

-(void)testProductService{
//Method where the mock object's method is invoked
ProductRequest *request = [[ProductRequest alloc] init];
[request testProductRequest];
}
```

I seems to always receive a method was not invoked exception. Please help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: can you please modify the code in a way that it becomes clear where you create the OCMockObject?

Comment: @Pfitz I added comments to my code, hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to replace the real request inside the real `ProductService`. You can archiev this for example by making the request a property of the `ProductService` like this:

```
@interface ProductService
@property (strong) ProductRequest *request
```

and then exchange the real ProductRequest with the mocked one like this

```
- (void)testProductService {
  id mockProductRequest = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[ProductRequest class]]; 
  [[mockProductRequest expect] testProductRequest];

  ProductService *actualService = [[ProductService alloc] init]; 
  actualService.request = mockProductReqeust;

  // call some method on actualService which invokes the request

  [request testProductRequest];


}
```

Comment: Thank you @Pfitz for providing an excellent example. It also clearly shows how to make your code testable.

Answer (score 2):

The aim of Mock Objects is to replace the objects you want to test. But in your code you send the message testProductRequest to a real ProductRequest and not to your MockObject !

Comment: Thanks @iSoftTom for guiding me to the correct path, much appreciated.